# .NET CORE Linq NullReferenceException using Auto Mapper

Tags: .net, .net-core

Using automapper I got NullException error when I try to get TeamId.

Once I comment out TeamName, I can get data from TeamMembers, but somehow when I tried to get TeamId its returning error.

```
    CreateMap<Match, MatchResource>()
        .ForMember(mr => mr.HomeTeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.HomeTeam.Name))
        .ForMember(mr => mr.AwayTeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.AwayTeam.Name))
        .ForMember(mr => mr.MatchRecords, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.MatchRecords.Select(mrs => new MatchRecordResource 
        { 
            Id = mrs.Id,
            MemberId = mrs.Member.Id, 
            MemberName = mrs.Member.Name,
            TeamMembers = mrs.Member.TeamMembers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.MemberId == mrs.Id),
            //TeamId = mrs.Member.TeamMembers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.MemberId == mrs.Id).TeamId,
            //TeamName = mrs.Member.TeamMembers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.MemberId == mrs.Id).Team.Name,
            CodeId = mrs.CodeId, 
            CodeName = mrs.Type.Name
        })));
```

Result data only with TeamMembers

```
 "matchRecords": [
                    {
                        "memberId": 1,
                        "memberName": "JakeLastTest23",
                        "codeId": 5,
                        "codeName": "Score",
                        "teamMembers": {
                            "memberId": 1,
                            "teamId": 1,
                            "member": {
                                "name": "JakeLastTest23",
                                "email": "jake.kw@iottie.com",
                                "phone": "132442",
                                "startedOn": "2020-01-27T05:00:00",
                                "roleId": 1,
                                "role": null,
                                "teamMembers": [],
                                "imageUrl": "https://www.iottie.com/download/profile-blank.png",
                                "dob": "1969-12-31T00:00:00",
                                "id": 1,
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-29T00:00:00",
                                "deletedAt": null
                            },
                            "team": {
                                "name": "Blue",
                                "logoUrl": null,
                                "history": null,
                                "startedOn": "2020-01-29T00:00:00",
                                "endedOn": null,
                                "club": null,
                                "clubId": 1,
                                "id": 1,
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-29T00:00:00",
                                "deletedAt": null
                            },
                            "isCaptain": false,
                            "id": 1,
                            "createdAt": "2020-01-29T00:00:00",
                            "deletedAt": null
                        },
                        "teamId": 0,
                        "teamName": null,
                        "matchId": 0,
                        "match": null,
                        "id": 1,
                        "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                        "deletedAt": null
                    },
```

My Member model:

public class Member : BaseEntity
{

```
public virtual List<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }

public Member()
{
    TeamMembers = new List<TeamMember>();
}
```

}

I don't understand, I can get TeamMember data, but can't get whats inside is weird. I also check the data before automapper function and it has Teamdata in TeamMember.

Anyone please help!

Additionally,

```
    CreateMap<Member, MemberResource>()
        .ForMember(mr => mr.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
        .ForMember(mr => mr.TeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.TeamMembers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.MemberId == m.Id).Team.Name))
        .ForMember(mr => mr.TeamId, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.TeamMembers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.MemberId == m.Id).Team.Id));
```

I could get the TeamName and TeamId from just member mapper.

Comment: Weirdly, TeamName = mrs.Member.TeamMembers.Where(f => f.MemberId == mrs.Id).Select(s => s.Team.Name).FirstOrDefault(), this worked. Anyone knows why? I don't see the difference getting data from just firstordefault right away.

Comment: That looks like an EF Core issue. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Run that as a LINQ statement, without AM. You should get the same result.